# Committing .classpath to SVN Repository Causes Project Execution Issues(Tomcat-Dynamic Web Project)

Tags: java, tomcat10

In a dynamic web project, one of the users mistakenly committed the .classpath file to the SVN repository. As a result, all the other users attempting to work on the project are facing issues when trying to run it with Tomcat.
Apache Tomcat version---10.1
Java --17
Dynamic Web Module--5.0
Eclise---2023-09

I tried to change dependencies in pom but its not working
the class path (xml)is same as previous (for other users even after updating the project)-but it is not running and throwing a class not found exception for my filter